# Storing an enum value in NHibernate as a string with space

Tags: c#, nhibernate, enums, fluent-nhibernate

I have the following enum in c#:

```
public enum AppraisalRating
{
    [Description("Please select a rating")]
    [EnumMember(Value = "N S")]
    NotSelected = -1,
    [Description("Not Rated")]
    [EnumMember(Value = "N R")]
    NotRated = 0
}
```

I want to store this in my database using NHibernate, but I want to store the EnumMember attribute value. If I have my mapping as:

```
Map(x => x.Rating)
```

This will simply store the enum value, e.g. `NotSelected` for the first item.

If I change my mapping to:

```
Map(x => x.Rating).CustomType<AppraisalRating>();
```

Then this will store the actual enum value, e.g. `-1` for `NotSelected` for the first item.

How can I use NHibernate to store the value from the EnumMember attribute? So I would want "N S" if I the enum value is `NotSelected`.

PS. Yes, I do need the spaces to be stored within the database due to integration with another system.

Comment: Found [this](http://cdmckay.org/blog/2009/07/12/how-to-put-spaces-in-your-nhibernate-enums/) article which works quite well, but I'd rather use attributes on the enum values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing a custom class for my enum which overrides methods used by NHibernate:

```
public class EnumWithValuesFromEnumMember<T> : NHib.Type.EnumStringType where T : struct
{
    public EnumWithValuesFromEnumMember()
        : base(typeof(T))
    {
    }

    public override object GetInstance(object enumCode)
    {
        var codeString = (string)enumCode;
        var type = typeof(T);
        if (!type.IsEnum) throw new InvalidOperationException();
        foreach (var field in type.GetFields())
        {
            if (Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field,
                typeof(EnumMemberAttribute)) is EnumMemberAttribute attribute)
            {
                if (attribute.Value == codeString)
                    return (T)field.GetValue(null);
            }
            else
            {
                if (field.Name == codeString)
                    return (T)field.GetValue(null);
            }
        }

        return default(T);
    }

    public override object GetValue(object enumCode)
    {
        var type = enumCode.GetType();
        var memberInfo = type.GetMember(enumCode.ToString());
        var attr = memberInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<EnumMemberAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
        return attr != null ? attr.Value : enumCode;
    }
}
```

With my mapping as:

```
Map(x => x.Rating).CustomType<EnumWithValuesFromEnumMember<AppraisalRating>>();
```

Now I can use the `EnumMember` attribute.